# Dynamic Distribution Groups - Description ID Field

Tags: windows, exchange, email-server, exchange-2010, distribution-lists

We have Exchange 2010, I am trying to create a dynamic distribution group that contains users with Exchange mailboxes, is within a certain OU and has a description of "xxxx".

I don't see the ability to filter based on the description field using the EMC.

Can you accomplish this task using the EMS? I've tried looking at the cmdlet **New-DynamicDistributionGroup**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this in EMS
New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name "GroupA" -RecipientFilter {( Description -eq 'xxxx') } -RecipientContainer "Users"
For your reference, [New-DynamicDistributionGroup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/new-dynamicdistributiongroup?view=exchange-ps)

Comment: Thanks, I read the documentation for that cmdlet but apparently didn't read enough.